# QTabWidget not styled correctly when using StyleSheet

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, qt-designer, qtstylesheets, qtabwidget

I am not able to properly style the QTabWidget using the StyleSheet in Qt Designer.

How can I style the tab buttons, the close buttons on them? There is a weird white bezel at the bottom? How can I remove them?
Here is the style sheet for it:

```
background-color: rgb(58, 68, 102);
border-radius: 4;
border-style: none;
```

Here is a minimal reproducible example:
The Python file:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PyQt5 import uic

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        #Loading teh ui file
        uic.loadUi('sir.ui', self)


QApp = QApplication([])

window = MainWindow()
window.show()

QApp.exec()
```

The ui file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
<class>MainWindow</class>
<widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
<property name="geometry">
<rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>805</width>
    <height>625</height>
</rect>
</property>
<property name="windowTitle">
<string>MainWindow</string>
</property>
<property name="styleSheet">
<string notr="true">background-color: rgb(38, 43, 68);</string>
</property>
<widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
<widget class="QTabWidget" name="tabWidget">
    <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
    <x>10</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>781</width>
    <height>581</height>
    </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="focusPolicy">
    <enum>Qt::TabFocus</enum>
    </property>
    <property name="contextMenuPolicy">
    <enum>Qt::DefaultContextMenu</enum>
    </property>
    <property name="acceptDrops">
    <bool>true</bool>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
    <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(58, 68, 102);
border-radius: 4;
border-style: none;</string>
    </property>
    <property name="tabPosition">
    <enum>QTabWidget::North</enum>
    </property>
    <property name="currentIndex">
    <number>0</number>
    </property>
    <property name="elideMode">
    <enum>Qt::ElideRight</enum>
    </property>
    <property name="tabsClosable">
    <bool>true</bool>
    </property>
    <property name="movable">
    <bool>true</bool>
    </property>
    <widget class="QWidget" name="tab_2">
    <attribute name="title">
    <string>Home</string>
    </attribute>
    </widget>
</widget>
</widget>
<widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
<property name="geometry">
    <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>805</width>
    <height>21</height>
    </rect>
</property>
</widget>
<widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
</widget>
<resources/>
<connections/>
</ui>
```

Here is the current state:

[image: (the image is here)]

Comment: please provide a [mre], explain yourself better since your question is unclear

Comment: An MRE should not depend on an external resource. Think that the objective of SO is to provide a quality Q&A, and if your answer depends on a link then the latter could break making your post useless. Please read the link, also read [ask] and review the [tour]

Comment: My Bad, sorry, I fixed it

Comment: @LeoRed what do you mean with "white bezel at the bottom"? Bottom of what? Also, if you want to style the button, you should not use generic style sheet (which is applied not only to the *whole* widget it's set for, but also all its children), but the proper selector. In this case, `QTabBar::close-button { ... }`. See [Customizing QTabWidget and QTabBar](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qtabwidget-and-qtabbar).

Comment: I am talking about the white bezel at the botton right of the Tabwidget. Also, thanks for clearing the doubt about styling the rest of the tab, the Link you gave is helpful

Comment: @LeoRed You're welcome. Be aware that "generic" stylesheets (like those you set) should normally be used only on very specific, simple widgets: labels, buttons, etc. QTabWidget is a *complex* widget, and it's also a *container* widget: setting a stylesheet like that results in setting those properties to **all** its children. In the case of QTabWidget this means: 1. the QTabWidget; 2. the tab bar (QTabBar); 3. each tab of the tab bar (if you set `color`, it will change the text color of the tab titles); 4. tab buttons; 5. scroll buttons; 6. *everything* that is added as page to the tab widget.

Comment: This is valid for *any* widget that can have children, which also means *scroll areas* (which not only have scrollable contents, but also other "internal" widgets, like the scroll bars or headers of item views). Using proper [selectors](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html#selector-types) ensures that you are correctly styling only the widgets you really want to customize, without changing the appearance of everything else they might contain. Remember that stylesheets are *inherited*: whenever a widget has a parent, it also inherits its stylesheet, and those of all of it parents.

Comment: Finally, complex widgets like QTabWidget do require more care with stylesheets, and that's because the current [platform] style might use the palette (which is partially altered by stylesheets) in different ways, and that's probably the reason of your issue. I cannot test your QSS on Windows, but that platform is known to use some peculiar painting depending on the situation, and complex widget normally require that you set *all* properties of its subcontrols too. I suggest you to carefully study all stylesheet related pages (and do lots of tests!), as Qt style sheets are as powerful as tricky